# Prove that $\forall n>3, n^2-4$ is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on this proof and I don't really know where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about$$n^2-4=(n-2)(n+2)$$?

Comment: Suppose n is odd, say of the form 2k+1.. can you expand $n^2-4=(2k+1)^2-4$...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik if I expand, I get 4k^2+4k-3. I still don't know how I would go about proving that's composite though

Comment: @MostafaAyaz oh that is a good idea!! thank you so much

Comment: Oh.. that was a bad hint.... You can follow what Mostafa said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method to show that any algebraic expression is composite is to factorise that expression.

$n^2-4=(n+2)(n-2)$
Also, $n>3 \implies (n-2)>1$

So, $\forall n>3$ $n^2-4$ can be written as product of two numbers none of which is equal to $1$. Hence , $n^2-4$ is composite $\forall n>3$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the experienced mathematician will notice:

$n^2 - 4 = (n-2)(n+2)$ and as $n > 3$ then $n-2 > 1$ so $n-2$ is a factor of $n^2 -4$ that is neither $1$ nor $n^2-4$.  (as is $n+2$).

......

BUt I guess the question is what to do if you *don't* notice that.

If $n$ is even than $4|n^2$ and $4|n^2 -2$ and so isn't prime.

Otherwise if $n$ is odd we have $n=2k+1$ for some $k$ (or we could alternately so $n =2j -1$) and so $n^2 -4 = 4k^2 + 4k +1 -4 = 4k^2 + 4k -3$ and... well, I guess it would probably occur to try to factor $4k^2 + 3k -3= (2k-1)(2k+3)$ but....

[Sidenote:  Notice $(2k-1) =n-2$ and $2k+3 = n+2$ so this is the exact same factoring as in the beginning.]

If it occurs to one to factor then, it *should* have occurred to factor in the very beginning.  (And factoring $n^2 -4$ is, IMO, easier than factoring $4k + 4k -3$.)

But.... sometimes one needs to be led to something.

....

What is probably *not* a good idea is induction.

If we assume $n^2 -4 = a*b$ then $(n+1)^2-4 = n^2-4 + 2n+1 =a*b +2n+1$ and... yeah, that will get you *nowhere*.